# R Shiny: varSelectInput only numeric variables from dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

In a shiny app I have a varSelectInput widget to select variables from the iris dataset. Is there a way where I can limit the variables in the varSelectInput to numeric variables only. I tried with is.numeric(iris), but no had no success. Thanks.

my code:

```
  library(shiny)
  library(ggplot2)
  
  # single selection
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      varSelectInput("variable", "Variable:", is.numeric(iris),
                     selected = NULL),
      
      plotOutput("data")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$data <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(iris, aes(!!input$variable)) + geom_histogram()
      })
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `Filter` :

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    varSelectInput("variable", "Variable:", Filter(is.numeric, iris),
                   selected = NULL),
    
    plotOutput("data")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$data <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(iris, aes(.data[[input$variable]])) + geom_histogram()
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: rather `names(Filter(is.numeric, iris))`, no?

Comment: yeah that is what I was expecting as well but `varSelectInput` requires input as dataframes from which it automatically takes the column names.

Comment: Ah yes? Didn't know that. I never used it actually.

Comment: Thank you Ronak and Stéphane.